# How to display FormGroup error in Angular 8

Tags: angular, forms, validation, formgroups

I have a textarea, which is required and needs at least 10 characters. If the user clicks the button and these criteria are `true`, I'd like to display an error message.

Here is my HTML-Code:

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGrp" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="input-field input-field--multiline">
    <textarea 
      rows="2"
      [formControl]="requestAccessMessageCtrl"
      [attr.placeholder]="Your message">
    </textarea>
    <!--add error message here-->
  </div>
  <div class="button-group button-group--responsive request__btn">
    <button class="button button--primary" type="submit">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is my TypeScript:

```js
readonly requestAccessMessageCtrl = new FormControl(null, {
    validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)],
  })
readonly formGrp = new FormGroup({ message: this.requestAccessMessageCtrl })

onSubmit() {
  if (this.requestAccessMessageCtrl.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  this.userService.postActivity(
    this.requestAccessMessageCtrl.value,
  )
}
```

What do I have to add to display two error messages:

1. "Input field is required"
2. "Type at least 10 characters"

I'd like to display the errors only if the user has pressed the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public isSubmitted;
```

and inside your `submit()` function set that variable to true.
and then in your html add it to your conditions.

```
<div class="text-danger" *ngIf="isSubmitted && requestAccessMessageCtrl.invalid && requestAccessMessageCtrl.errors?.minlength ">
      <small>Need at least 10 characters</small>
</div>

<div class="text-danger" *ngIf="isSubmitted && requestAccessMessageCtrl.invalid && requestAccessMessageCtrl.errors?.required">
           <small>Field is required</small>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but not that way which I like. The should only display when the user press the button. If the textarea is empty the "Field is required" should appear when the user clicks the button

Comment: declare some flag say  isSubmitted in ts file and set it to true on submit function. Then use condition like *ngIf="requestAccessMessageCtrl.invalid && requestAccessMessageCtrl.errors?.required && isSubmitted  "

Comment: @macintosh as Shikha said, just add a variable in there, and set it on submit function to true. see my updated answer

Comment: great that works! Is it possible to change the textarea border color to red if the error appears?

Comment: yes. Add some class with property border:red using ngclass directive specifying the same *ngIf condition

Comment: @Shikha could you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

Add below in css file

```
.invalid {
    border-color: red;
    }
```

Add below code in ts file

```
<div class="input-field input-field--multiline">
        <textarea rows="2"
            [ngClass]="{'invalid':isSubmitted && requestAccessMessageCtrl.invalid && requestAccessMessageCtrl.errors?.minlength}"
            [formControl]="requestAccessMessageCtrl" [attr.placeholder]="Your message">
                    </textarea>
<div class="text-danger"
            *ngIf="isSubmitted && requestAccessMessageCtrl.invalid && requestAccessMessageCtrl.errors?.minlength ">
            <small>Need at least 10 characters</small>
</div>
<div class="text-danger"
            *ngIf="isSubmitted && requestAccessMessageCtrl.invalid && requestAccessMessageCtrl.errors?.required">
            <small>Field is required</small>
 </div></div>
<div class="button-group button-group--responsive request__btn">
    <button class="button button--primary" type="submit">Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: for sure I added it in the .css file

Comment: I had to replace the `&&` operator with `||` operator

Answer (score 0):

please find the code below-

html-

```
    <form [formGroup]="formGrp">
    <div class="input-field input-field--multiline">
        <textarea
      rows="2"
      formControlName="message"
      >
    </textarea>
        <div *ngIf="showError">
            <span *ngIf="formGrp.get('message').errors?.required">Input field is required</span>
            <span *ngIf="formGrp.get('message').errors?.minlength">Type at least 10 characters</span>
        </div>
        <!--add error message here-->
    </div>
    <div class="button-group button-group--responsive request__btn">
        <button class="button button--primary" (click)="onSubmit()"type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and in the component-

```
showError = false;
    onSubmit() {
    if (this.requestAccessMessageCtrl.invalid) {
      this.showError = true;
      return;
  }
    this.showError = false;
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag9ken)